# Marshalling of boolean values using JAXB issue

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

I have a boolean attribute in a java class `private boolean isCurrent;` Now in xml it gets marshalled into `<current>false</current>` . Now the field i have is only `isCurrent`. How do i preserve the name `isCurrent` as it is in XML?. Though i know it is not related to getters & setter s of the boolean just for information, they are named as setCurrent & isCurrent taking the defaults of eclipse IDE.

Comment: Show us your code. Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Perhaps rename the field to `current` but as I have a POJO successfully marshaled using the present field name, add your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A presence of an empty tag could be mapped to a boolean. For e.g. `<isPresent/>`
Use an XmlAdaptor:

```
package com.example.xml.adaptor;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BooleanToEmptyObjectAdapter extends XmlAdapter<EmptyObject, Boolean> {
    @Override
    public EmptyObject marshal(final Boolean v) {
        return v != null && v ? new EmptyObject() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(final EmptyObject v) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a dummy object for it to serialize:

```
package com.example.xml.adaptor;

public class EmptyObject {
    // EMPTY
}
```

Then in your object, use a Boolean (not a boolean) field:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FooElement")
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement()
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanToEmptyObjectAdapter.class)
    private final Boolean isPresent = false;

    ...        
}
```